# Writing with Python Greek letters to (Oracle) SQL file doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write Greek letters to file with ".sql" extension. But the result in the file are not correct.

The code in Python:

```
with open('test.sql', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as test_file:
    test_file.write('DH5α\n')
```

In the SQL file I get:

```
DH5Î±
```

Any way I can solve this?

OS is windows

Thanks.

Comment: how are you opening the file? Likely whatever program you are using is not using the correct encoding, in this case, utf-8

Comment: Correct, the file is opened in sql-developer. I had to change in sql-developer the encoding to UTF-8. I thought that [encoding='utf-8'] in the python function is already handling this, but I guess it's not.

Comment: That handles what the *file contains*. Not how it is being interpreted by some other program. If you are on windows, likely it assumes "latin" encoding i.e. ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

From the cx_Oracle documentation [Character Sets and Globalization](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html) make sure your connections are opened with the right character set.

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString, encoding="US-ASCII", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

Note that with cx_Oracle 8, the defaults changed to be "UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

As written in comments, the problem was with sql-developer itself, which didn't use utf-8 encoding by default.